# strange behaviour of .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewrite-module

I have a .htaccess file on my website's root directory to hide the .php part from URL.
It works great. But it fails on media.php file.
When i call a URL for example domain.com/idea.php it returns to domain.com/idea [as I expected.].
But for media.php it returns to domain.com/media/ [and it shows the 403 forbidden page]
I don't have any idea about how it is coming.

```
here is my code on .htaccess file:

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## don't touch /forum URIs
RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Do you have a directory called `media`?

Comment: NO, i dont. I just have media.php